# Concatenate two functions in a result

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to add this as one of my columns:

`REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(dbo.new_truck.new_Description| CHAR(13)| '<br>')| CHAR(10)| '<br>')| '"'| 'in')+'Location: '+IF(dbo.new_truck.ditl_Inventory=True,'Vancouver','Edmonton')`

But after executing the SELECT, SQL Server changes it to this:
`REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(dbo.new_truck.new_Description| CHAR(13)| '<br>')| CHAR(10)| '<br>')| '"'| 'in') + 'Location: ' + 'IF(dbo.new_truck.ditl_Inventory=True,[Edmonton],[Vancouver])'`

It appears that I cannot concatenate a function with a string, with another function. If I take everything after "Location:" out, of course, it works. But without the location :)

Any other way to accomplish this? I could write this into the PHP code that handles the output of this query, but thought I'd try this first

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you mean "SQL Server changes it"? Are you using some graphical query designer? Please stop doing that; write your T-SQL in a normal query window.

Comment: Also, inline IF, | as a concatenation operator, and Boolean expressions like true are not concepts that work in SQL Server. Is this actually Access or some other database platform?

Comment: This is in SQL Server Management Studio. The original field was just
`REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(dbo.new_truck.new_Description| CHAR(13)| '<br>')| CHAR(10)| '<br>')| '"'| 'in') `

Which works just fine. I'm just trying to add on the "Location: " part to the end

Comment: Sorry I guess I should mention, when I say "SQL Server changes it", I mean, as soon as I Tab out of the column in the designer, it replaces it with what I quoted.

Comment: So first step is to stop using the designer, because that code will never work in SQL Server anyway - the fact that it allows it in any form is a testament to the quality of the designer. Next step is to use Transact-SQL constructs that actually make sense - `|` is not a concatenation operator, for example, you use `+` or `,` (tough to tell the intention of the nested replace calls).

Comment: Looks like the |'s are not meant to be concatenation operators - they're function value separators like a comma commonly is. I don't know why I have them as pipes and not commas though...


Designer seems to only allow me to do things that SQL Server is capable of; what else am I supposed to use to build/debug queries? I hardly work with the DB but I'm the only IT guy here and this his kinda how I 'learned' to do it.

Comment: When I try to use as a computed column definition I get `Error validating the formula for column 'whatever'. Do you want to cancel your changes?` How exactly are you entering this formula and are you sure it's working the way you think? Have you ever successfully returned results from a query that includes that code?

Comment: Also, how exactly do you find that the visual designers make it easier to build/debug your queries than just writing them out? If anything, the visual designers make it *harder* to write queries because they re-format your code, have a variety of bugs, lack support for some query constructs, and produce vague error messages. I guess on the plus side you can check boxes instead of typing column names and pick data types from drop-downs...

Comment: P.S. [I may have blogged about this](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/14/bad-habits-to-kick-using-the-visual-designers).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22879/discussion-between-justincredible-and-aaron-bertrand).

Answer (score 0):

I have instead edited my PHP code that handles this data:

`//Show the location in the truck description 
if ($mainrow[24] == "0") { 
$mainrow[16] = $mainrow[16] . " Location: Edmonton"; 
} else if ($mainrow[24]=="1") { 
$mainrow[16] = $mainrow[16] . " Location: Vancouver"; 
}`

where `$mainrow[24]` is the "Inventory" column, and `$mainrow[16]` is the Description column.